# TCP: Python to Node

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, tcp

This might be a basic question, or it might not be. I'm trying to make a stream from a python client to a node.js server over TCP. I'm basically going to be passing data to and from a program called ren'py to some devices on the other end of the node server. Its running on localhost and ports. I'm not sure how keep the client open (currently reading up in the socket doc, but thought I'd ask here as well).

Maybe its better to make a python server and a node client?

Anyways, here's my very basic start. Suggestions? Thanks.

Super Basic Node Server:

```
    var net = require('net');
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT =  '1337';

var server = net.createServer(function(socket){
    //console.log('client connected');
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + socket.remoteAddress +':'+ socket.remotePort);
    // Add a 'data' event handler to this instance of socket
    socket.on('data', function(data){
        console.log('DATA ' + socket.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
        // Write the data back to the socket, the client will receive it as data from the server
        socket.write('You said '+ data);
    });

    socket.on('end', function(){
        console.log('client disconnected');
    });


});
```

Super Basic Python Client:

```
import socket
import sys

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error, msg:
    print 'Failed to create socket. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ' , Error message : ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket Created'

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 1337


s.connect((host, port))

message = "Hello"

try:
    #Set the whole string
    s.sendall(message)

except socket.error:
    #Send failed
    print 'Send failed'
    sys.exit()

print 'Message Sent!'
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? What do you mean by "keep the client open?"

Comment: Sure. Right now the python client connects, sends, and closes immediately. I need the client to connect and stay connected to the node server so that the client and the server can send messages back and forth to each other until I prompt either the client to disconnect or I prompt the server to close.